# PHP checking preg_match for a match

Tags: php, string, preg-match

I am searching for urls within strings from an array

Some strings may contain more than one URL and other strings may have just plain text

if the string contains 1 or more URLs then i want to write store only them urls in a table.

otherwise if it contains Only text, I still want to store that text in a table.

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
         $urlList = $urlArrayVal[0]; //String within array
            $regex = '/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i'; 
            preg_match_all($regex, $urlList, $matches);
            $urls = $matches[0];
            var_dump($urls);
            // go over all links
            foreach($urls as $url) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO urls (url) VALUES ('$urls')";
                mysqli_query( $link, $sql);
            }
```

I am now stuck. this will write only the URLS (if any) to a table, ignoring the strings that have plain text.

Any help is appreaciated

EDIT: also, if one string has more than 1 URL, i would like to store all of the URLs in that one string to one row in a table.

Comment: Count the number of matches, if there are none, add the plain text.

Comment: @doge thanks, I took your advice and I managed to solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use preg_match_all on each string, not the entire array:

```php
$sql="INSERT INTO urls (url) VALUES ";
for($i=0; $i<count($urlList), $i++)
{
 $numMatches=preg_match_all($regex, $urlList[$i], $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
 if(!$numMatches)
 {
   //handle the error
 }
 else if($numMatches==0)
 {
   //no url's found
   //save $urlList[$i] (the string) somewhere if you want
 }
 else if($numMatches>0)
 {
   //found urls, append them in the query
   for($j=0;$j<count($matches[0]);$j++)
    $sql.=" ('".$matches[0][$j]."'),"
 }
 else
 {
   //this shouldn't happen
 }      
}
rtrim($sql, ",")//remove the last comma from the query
mysqli_query( $link, $sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

If i use this all will Work:

```
<?php
$urlList = 'something
something and http://www.url.com and so on
and 2 http://www.3url.com or http://www.2url.com in a row';
$regex = '/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i'; 
preg_match_all($regex, $urlList, $matches);
$urls = $matches[0];
var_dump($urls);
// go over all links
foreach($urls as $url) {
    echo$sql = "INSERT INTO urls (url) VALUES ('$url')";
    mysqli_query( $link, $sql);
}
?>
```

You have to get us a example string to test better your problem.

Comment: However, I tried this eariler (it works) but if the string has more than 1 url, it will insert them into different rows.

Comment: ok i think i anderstand you ... frist split the text in multiple rows like ´preg_split('/\r\n/',$string)´ and match the rows ... if no url found save the text else `implode($matches[0])` the matches and save to db